# How to handle dynamicly created objects in pycharm IDE?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm creating many dynamic objects in an `__init__.py` file. I understand I could choose to not do this, but I am asking for the scenario where I decide to do this.

For example in `example/__init__.py` I have

```
class Example:
   pass 

globals()['SubExample'] = Example
```

Now I can run

```
from example import SubExample
```

It will run fine, but my pycharm IDE will not recognise this as it's created only on run time. Is there any way to make it recognise this?

Note that you can ignore import errors with `#noqa`, but I would like pycharm to understand that this class will exist.

Comment: It sounds like PyCharm is being the voice of reason here :)

Comment: No, it's not going to do static analysis on dynamically created variables.